# htaccess index files issue - html5boilerplate

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, indexing, html5boilerplate

I'm using **html5boilerplate** .htaccess file on one of my projects and i'm having some problems trying to make it works properly.
The main problem is that **on sub-directories** the index.hmtl file won't load **automatically** if you type in the address bar its main directory path.

If you try to access to http://provaeur.altervista.org/sitovino/en/wines/ you can see an **example**. In the directory "wines" there is actually an index.html file but instead of the index you can see a 403 error :(

I've tried to comment these lines:

```
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

but it seems not to be the solution.

Here you can find a .txt copy of my .htaccess file:

http://provaeur.altervista.org/sitovino/htaccess.txt

Thanks for helping an italian noob :)